# Do you know a way to fix a Ext4 partition that is mounted, fstab but still won't work * lost+found?

Tags: partitioning, mount, kubuntu

I installed Kubuntu 22.04 Kernel Ver. 6.2.0-31, and it partitioned a Ext4 on my SSD for the system and left my previous files on a NTFS partition. I did not really need the old files so I tried to partition the rest of the drive to Ext4 so it all could be used by Kubuntu installations. (It is Not a dual boot) The drive does not work and shows lost+found file.

It shows up in the terminal, in Dolphin, and KDE Partition Mgr.
Using KDE Partition Manager, I unmounted, I deleted it, reformatted it Ext4, relabeled it SSD2, and it automatically mounted. I try to use the drive, all that is there is a lost and found folder, and it reads "could not enter folder /home/unity/media/lost+found"
First attempt I used the terminal with the exact same results. I have looked in the fstab and it shows there.

I got the name home/unity/media from a path presented by KDE Partition Manager I believe when setting the mount point.

```
$ stat /home/unity/media
  File: /home/unity/media
  Size: 4096            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 801h/2049d      Inode: 2           Links: 3
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2023-09-01 18:13:28.895361456 -0500
Modify: 2023-09-01 18:11:32.000000000 -0500
Change: 2023-09-01 18:11:32.000000000 -0500
 Birth: 2023-09-01 18:11:32.000000000 -0500
$
$ findmnt --fstab
TARGET            SOURCE                                    FSTYPE OPTIONS
/                 UUID=8256fca0-2723-4e9a-bc64-ac669b1cdd7d ext4   errors=remount-ro
/boot/efi         UUID=A9EF-3FF7                            vfat   umask=0077
none              /swapfile                                 swap   sw
/home/unity/media /dev/sda1
$

                         ext4   rw,relatime,errors=remoun
└─/var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell /dev/sda5[/usr/share/hunspell] ext4   ro,noexec,noatime,errors=
                     ext4   rw,relatime,errors=remoun
├─/var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell /dev/sda5[/usr/share/hunspell] ext4   ro,noexec,noatime,errors=
└─/home/unity/media
```

```
df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs           1.6G  1.6M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/sda5        74G   16G   54G  23% /
tmpfs           7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
/dev/sda1       145G   28K  138G   1% /home/unity/media
/dev/sda2       512M  6.1M  506M   2% /boot/efi
tmpfs           1.6G   52K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sdb1       100M   26M   75M  26% /media/unity/SYSTEM
/dev/sdb5        98G   89M   98G   1% /media/unity/New Volume
/dev/sdb2       1.8T  422G  1.4T  25% /media/unity/MAIN DRIVE
```

```
lsblk -e 7
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sda      8:0    0 223.6G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0 148.2G  0 part /home/unity/media
├─sda2   8:2    0   513M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda3   8:3    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0  74.8G  0 part /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell
                                 /
sdb      8:16   0   1.8T  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0   100M  0 part /media/unity/SYSTEM
├─sdb2   8:18   0   1.7T  0 part /media/unity/MAIN DRIVE
├─sdb3   8:19   0     1K  0 part 
├─sdb4   8:20   0  11.2G  0 part 
└─sdb5   8:21   0  97.7G  0 part /media/unity/New Volume
sdc      8:32   1     0B  0 disk 
sdd      8:48   1     0B  0 disk 
sde      8:64   1     0B  0 disk 
sdf      8:80   1     0B  0 disk 
sr0     11:0    1   1.6G  0 rom
```

```
findmnt -t ext4
```

TARGET                                   SOURCE                         FSTYPE OPTIONS
/                                        /dev/sda5                      ext4   rw,relatime,errors=remoun
└─/var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell /dev/sda5[/usr/share/hunspell] ext4   ro,noexec,noatime,errors=

This is what I tried.

```
unity@unity-p7-1297c:~$ sudo umount /home/unity/media
```

unity@unity-p7-1297c:~$ sudo rmdir /home/unity/media

unity@unity-p7-1297c:~$ sudo mkdir /mnt/SSD2

unity@unity-p7-1297c:~$ sudo mount -t auto /dev/sda1 /mnt/SSD2

unity@unity-p7-1297c:~$ sudo chmod a+rwx /mnt/SSD2/

***The sda1 drive is mounted and working in home/unity/media and the /mnt/SSD2 folder is EMPTY....

Edited the fstab and moved the mount point from
/home/unity/media to /mnt/SSD2

```
sudo umount /home/unity/media
```

sudo nano /etc/fstab
sudo mount /mnt/SSD2

The drive works and mounted in the correct folder.

Comment: Can you try formatting using the KDE Partition manager or GParted?

Comment: If you want a partition to be shown in dolphin, mount it somewhere under `/media`, for example `/media/data`. If you mount a partition elsewhere like in your case `/home/unity/SSD2` the partition will not be displayed in dolphin, but you can browse to the mountpoint to explore the contents of the partition.

Comment: A fresh formattet partition is empty exept the `lost+found`-folder which is owned by _root_, as a normal user you cannot enter this folder.This folder should be empty since its a new partition. I don't see anything wrong here. What do you mean when you say `the drive does not work`?

Comment: When I select the partitioned drive (SSD2) the only thing on the drive is that lost+found folder, when I open it Dolphin file mgr. "Could not enter folder /home/unity/media/lost+found. When I run lsblk -f it shows it mounted at 0% (I can not put anything on the drive)

Comment: @Nishnabe `/home/unity/media` is not a standard mount point. How exactly did you mount it there? Add the output of `stat /home/unity/media`  to the post using a [code block] please

Comment: ... Also please add the output of `findmnt --fstab` and of `findmnt -t ext4`

Comment: @mook765 ... Better to wait on `chmod` for now, I think ... `/dev/sda1` should be the EFI partition and there appears nothing to be actually mounted at `/home/unity/media` ... @Nishnabe Please, also add the output of `df -h` and `lsblk -e 7`

Comment: It appears that you skipped copying part of the last line in the output of `findmnt -t ext4` … Your filesystem, however, seems to be mounted and ready to use … `lost+found` is created with the filesystem as part of the other special inodes and it has permissions only for the `root` Owner user and none for group or others …  In addition to setting permissions on the mount point, the mount options `user,exec` in `fstab` might help as well … @mook765 Sorry for holding you back on a false alarm :-) … It’s your call now.

Comment: You will need to run `sudo chown USER: /home/unity/media` while the partition is mounted. You created the mountpoint with `sudo` thus it's owned by _root_, own it back to your user and you will be able to paste and copy files into it.

Comment: `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /home/unity/media`

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a live Cd/Dvd?
I would boot using a live disc and adjust these aforementioned settings without initiating your drives, or "locking" them by use.

You could also use the KDE or gparted partition managers to run repairs and other diagnostics. While in the live environment you could still enter terminal commands.

Unless this is resolved I would give that a shot.

Comment: is it mission critical data?

Comment: Let me re-phrase some questions are sent in by users that are trying to salvage critical data. If you have a means to back up all your data and reinstall, and you don't mind. then do that.  It might just be the right fix?

Comment: It is not critical data. The drive is mounted and full access. So the problem is solved. So my concern is the step I missed, I feel it compromises the questions, full solution.

Answer (score 0):

I installed Kubuntu 22.04 and I selected the option to partition the drive. Kubuntu created a Ext4 Partition for the Boot and the Operating System aka (root) and made a NTFS Partition and conveniently left all the files from the previous  Windows 7 OS on that drive. I had backed up those Windows 7 files on another drive already, and when I realized that TimeShift would not use a NTFS file system, I decided I would make the NTFS Partition into a Ext4, so it could be used as such.

I used KDE Partition Manager to reformat the drive from NTFS to Ext4 with no problems. However I placed the Mount Point in a unusual place on the (root) drive /home/unity/media. Also I did not know how to take ownership and control of that Mount Point (drive). So what I had was a drive with a "lost+found" folder which is supposed to be there, that I could not use. So I needed to take ownership and control.

chown is an abbreviation for “changing owner”, which is pretty self-explanatory.
While chmod handles what users can do with a file once they have access to it,
chown assigns ownership.

- whoami cmd reveals user.

BE CAREFUL WITH CHOWN. I'm the only user on my device and these are chown examples,
you have to study and research all these commands.

KONSOLE Terminal. Changed owner.

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /home/unity/media
```

sudo chown -R unity:admins /home/unity/media

Changed what I can do with files.

```
sudo chmod a+rwx /home/unity/media
```

Now I want to move my Mount Point to a more practical location,
from /home/unity/media to /mnt/SSD2.
So I needed to edit the fstab.

First I made a new Mount Point (aka new folder)

```
sudo mkdir /mni/SSD2
```

I unmounted the old Mount Point

```
sudo umount /home/unity/media
```

I open the fstab editor

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

Then I replaced /home/unity/media with /mnt/SSD2 in fstab and saved it.
I mounted the new Mount Point

```
sudo mount /mnt/SSD2
```

That fixed the problem and I'm able to use the drive. I'm a beginner and hope this helps others like me,
if any Veteran users see any problems with my answer, I would appreciate help in fixing it. (my research involved many hours of reading a lot of websites, too many to cite; the biggest key to finding the solution to this problem was senior members, mook765, raffa and muru sharing their insight)